# Phones won't load local test website

Tags: html, responsive-design, server, local

I'm working against the Google deadline for decent mobile access.

I have a local site running on 192.168.15.180.  I can access that site from other computers on my local network, and from an iPad.

However when I try to load it from an iPhone 4 running ios6 or an iPhone 5 running iOS7, they don't load.  Progress bar loads about 20%, and it hangs.

Doing an update to my main server, and everything works.

There are only two differences I can see:

Locally I have a different hostname.  If this were an issue I'd expect it to affect other computers on my home network.

The program does call the usual google analytic js script.  But then I'd expect it to affect the iPad too.

Other ideas?

Comment: Are the two phones on your wifi network as well?

Comment: And no I would never think it was the google analytic software

Comment: Both phones are on my wifi network.  Both partially load the page.

Comment: lets go to chat [click here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107432/hellllpppppppp)